# Epson Printer Utility not working

Tags: drivers, printing

My CPU: intel i5 64 bit processor.

Ubuntu: 18.04.1 LTS BB.

Bought a new Epson L380 inktank and down loaded the 64 bit drivers and the epson printer utility from the epson download centre website. Printing and photocopying work very well. However the epson printer utility program that is invoked from the command line using a terminal which is used to check ink levels and clean heads says:

> epson-printer-utility: error while loading shared libraries:
>   libQtCore.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory.

Has anybody encountered this? What should I do.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem in Ubuntu 20.04 but there were no chances to install qt4, also trying to build the file from the source code failed several times until I decided to do the following. This is not a perfect solution but in the end, it works.

The solution is to download and extract only the three missing files from qt4.

The procedure is:

Package: libqtcore4
    Contains: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4

```
Download from: http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/q/qt4-x11/libqtcore4_4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

Package: libqtgui4
    Contains: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4

```
Download from: http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/q/qt4-x11/libqtgui4_4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

Package: libpng12-0
    Contains: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0

```
Download from: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
```

Download the files to /tmp

cd /tmp

mkdir output

dpkg-deb -x libqtcore4_4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2_amd64.deb output

dpkg-deb -x libqtgui4_4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2_amd64.deb output

dpkg-deb -x libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb output

cd output

find . -name libQtCore.so.4

```
 ./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
```

find . -name libQtGui.so.4

```
 ./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
```

find . -name libpng12.so.0

```
 ./lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0
```

Copy the 3 files to: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

try epson-printer-utility, it should work now

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I just had to install `apt install libaudio2` too. First initialization of printer utility not workd. After restart it (only the utility) everything worked.

Comment: yeh, otherwise it is `libaudio.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: Still having `Communication daemon down, Error code = -1` any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by installing the following 3 packages using synaptic package manager. You can always use apt-get but I felt comfortable with synaptic as it gets all the dependencies also and all these packages have dependencies. The 3 packages  are : libqtcore4,  libqtgui4 and libcanberra-gtk-module. This will take care of the missing shared libraries as well as one more complaint the utility will make without the canberra module. That's it, after which it works well. Just one more note : To find out which package contains a shared library the apt-file app can be used to find out. e.g.   apt-file search libQtCore.so.4 will come back with the package name libqtcore4 which can be downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to install printer-driver-espr

`sudo apt install printer-driver-escpr`

After do it, go to ubuntu printer configuration. You can setting up by wifi too (printer must be connected to the same network)