# Vanishing Epson printer utility

Tags: software-installation, printing, epson

I just installed a printer utility which enables me to check ink levels. The deb file came directly from Epson's download page, and Ubuntu handled the installation smoothly. But I can't find the utility! It's not crucial because I can still print. Where does stuff like this vanish to? It's not in the "Show Applications" list. When I ran Windows, the utility would pop up when ink was low, but it could also be called from a desktop icon.

The install file is: epson-printer-utility_1.1.1-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb

Comment: Did you check your Desktop Search for the utility?

Comment: Yes, and all it finds is the installation file for the utility.

Comment: What happens if you open a terminal and enter `epson-printer-utility` ?

Comment: Result: epson-printer-utility: error while loading shared libraries: libQtCore.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
And I just found another thread about this problem, so I'll head over there. I'm curious though: Is there a version of Linux which handles these things in a way which doesn't turn it into a second job? Maybe a version with paid support?

Comment: Probably. Or I'll live without the utility for now. It's a convenience, and all of its functions can be performed on the printer itself. Thanks for your input.

Comment: I wonder if Ubuntu deals more smoothly with other brands - maybe HP or something. Who knows.....

Comment: It's the other way around. You encountered problems because Epson's support for Linux (not "Linux support for Epson") is deficient in this product; the author has let it become stale and the dependencies are not out-of-date. It's usually a fairly simple matter for the author (manufacturer) to update the build to use current dependencies, or to package the software so that it requires no dependencies at all. Some manufacturers provide excellent support. Some are terrible.

Answer (score 0):

Try `ls -la /usr/bin | grep epson` on the terminal and check if there is output.

Comment: That produced this result:
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root          52 Nov 15 20:18 epson-printer-utility -> /opt/epson-printer-utility/bin/epson-printer-utility

I just came from a Windows environment. Am I supposed to find a folder called "opt" and try running the bin file?

Comment: @Ancient nono. That is just to check if it was in the path. Now just type `epson-printer-utility` on the terminal and that should execute the program you've installed.

Comment: I just tried that. Result: epson-printer-utility: error while loading shared libraries: libQtCore.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I think there are some clues at this thread:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1111562/epson-printer-utility-not-working?rq=1